# Can A Maven Dependency Be Executable?

Tags: java, maven

I am creating a generic utils maven project. I have added this utils project as a dependency into my main maven project. It looks like I can use plugins in my utils pom to generate an executable jar. If the jar is executable, could I run it in my main project by adding it as a dependency? If I can, how do I add the path of the dependency to the `exec-maven-plugin`?

main_pom.xml

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.2.1</version>
 <executions>
  <execution>
   <id>default-cli</id>
   <goals>
    <goal>exec</goal>
   </goals>
   <configuration>
    <executable>java</executable>
    <arguments>
     <argument>-jar</argument>
     <!-- How can I get the dependency path here? -->
     <argument>path/to/executable-dependency-jar/name.jar</argument>
    </arguments>
   </configuration>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

I want it as a dependency for convenience. But I don't know if a dependency can be executable. And I don't know how to get the dependency path as shown above in the xml. My idea was to:

- Add an executable dependency.
- Add maven exec plugin to run the
  executable dependency as shown above.
- When I want my utils ran I
  would just have to execute `mvn exec:exec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but you can have an executable jar, and use it in another project.

But in this case, you don't need to call it as an executable. This is way simpler to just call some java code.

An executable jar is basically a jar with at least one class containing a valid main method (plus a manifest to know which class is the main class).

You can use this class from your Java code, without going "out" of the jvm, and use your jar as an executable.

And yet, you keep the ability to call your executable jar from outside (i.e from command line).

Typically, you have a business method doStuff(some signature), that you can call from any java code (this might be a static method) and main methods that just parses the command line arguments and calls the doStuff method.

Comment: I made it a jar because I wanted the convenience to just add it as a dependency and forget about it. So I could do `mvn exec:exec` and it runs my util jar. In your way would I have to just manually add the java classes into my project?

Comment: Added some more info to the question.

Comment: If you want to use the code from a jar from another java project, you don't need it to be excutable. Making a jar executable will allow you to run from "outside java", meaning that you can run in in command line, provided that you have a jre installed.

Comment: So in you case, this is just a regular maven dependency. If will be included in you artefact by maven (how this will be done depends on the nature of the project). If this is a web project, maven will put the jar in WEB-INF lib of the war, and voila !

Comment: Oh that makes sense - thanks. This is not a web project, just a normal maven project, nothing special. Let me see if I can find where the jars are located.

Comment: A "normal" maven project is not executable by default. Usually you use the assembly plugin (for instance to build a jar-with-dependencies or for some custom build) or something similar to build the project.